# For large data sets, how can one create a counter that is not computationally expensive?

Tags: r

In Statistics, often times count data can be used for many purposes. I currently have a large data column (around 600 million rows) which is called "A". It looks something like so:

```
A       
0       
0       
0       
1       
0       
1       
1       
0       
0       
0       
0       
1       
0       
1       
0
```

Here, A is just a bunch of 0 and 1's with no pattern. The 1's represent a "hit". Hence, I would like to keep a counter (starting at 1 instead of 0) that keeps track of how many hits have occurred+1.

```
A       Counter
0       1
0       1
0       1
1       2
0       2
1       3
1       4
0       4
0       4
0       4
0       4
1       5
0       5
1       6
0       6
```

I have come up with a for-loop that is:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(A){
Counter[i+1] <- df[i,5]+df[i+1,4]

}
```

However, the entire look takes forever at 600 million rows. Does anyone know a good fix? This seems simple but I just cant think of it. Any tips would be greatly helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have your data in a data.frame. If you have really 600 million rows there, you should have a look at package data.table.

Answer (score 5):

You want to calculate the cumulative sum:

```
Counter <- cumsum(A) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about not creating the counter afterwards but doing it when saving the hit/no-hit? Retrieve your last value and set the counter depending on this last value. For performance maybe even use a separate record to save the last value?